# Aliased rm, how do I also alias sudo rm

Tags: sudo, rm

I aliased `rm` to a `echo use del or full path to rm` to save myself from accidental rm (just lost my `$HOME` to it).

But `sudo rm` still uses `/bin/rm`. How can I alias it to also print same message?

PS: `del` is alias to `trash-put`

Comment: `sudo rm` is even more dangerous than just `rm`. I want just `sudo /bin/rm` to work and not `sudo rm`.

Comment: in `~/.zshrc` file

Comment: There isn't any `/root/.zshrc` should I create it?

Answer (score 0):

You could install you own version of **rm** in /usr/local/bin which is searched before /usr/bin where **rm** is.

Make a file 'sudo nano /usr/local/bin/rm' with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo use del of full path to rm
```

Remember to make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rm
```

**EDIT**

I don't think it a good idea to change the semantic behavior of 'rm'. A lot of other programs and scripts are using 'rm' and expect it to behave in the normal way.

Comment: I think it is dangerous for unexperienced users trying it, and messing up their system. It's bad to replace rm by a null command, that finishes sucessfully, that is, whith exit code `0`, clearly indicating that there was no error with calling `rm`. That's very wrong, so it should at least do an `exit 1` after the echo. But anyway, how do you want to prevent system tools to use the invalid `rm`? I do not think it's good if apt-get can not update anything at all, because it can not remove the old version. Hmm...sorry, I did not mean to sound rough, just trying to defuse this ;)

Comment: Agree.. That why I edited my answer a few hours later - to warn about changing the semantic behavior of 'rm'